# Why are TDD tests methods so static?

Tags: tdd

I watched a couple of videos about test driven developement and I mostly understand it. But there is the fact that in all of the videos I have watched that the methods are so static. So in my example the monster must always have 100 hitpoints and the attacker has 70. So what has this to do with testing when you only could cover one case?

An example test:

```
monster = Monster.new
monster.hitpoints = 100

hero = Hero.new
hero.strength = 70

hero.attack(monster)
monster.hitpoints.should == 30
```

And here is the code:

```
class Monster
    attr_accessor :hitpoints
end

class Hero
    attr_accessor :strength
    def attack(monster)
        monster.hitpoints -= strength
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test methods are static because you're watching videos. They are giving you the concepts and the syntax of testing frameworks, not necessarily "best" or "real-world" practices.

In your example there are some edge cases you'll want to check which will result in very similar looking tests. So factor out that common code.

```
def test_post_attack_hitpoints(initial, strength, expected):
  monster = Monster.new
  monster.hitpoints = initial

  hero = Hero.new
  hero.strength = strength

  hero.attack(monster)
  monster.hitpoints.should == expected
end

test_post_attack_hitpoints(100, 70, 30)
test_post_attack_hitpoints(100, 110, -10) # do you actually expect -10?
test_post_attack_hitpoints(100, -10, 110) # can a hero's strength go negative? Should that heal the monster?
```

In general videos and tutorials are going to teach you the absolute minimum to let you do something. Learning to do things *well* is a matter of experience. Start by learning from other people's experiences. Look at how unit tests are structured in well regarded open source projects. I can't necessarily point you at good examples in the Ruby world, but the test suite for Rails has certainly been exercised extensively and is probably a reasonable place to start. See how they organize things.

Then learn from your own experience. Write a bunch of unit tests. What works well, what seems dumb? Find a style that solves your own (or your team's) needs and do that.

I'll get off my soapbox now.

Answer (score 2):

It's completely intentional doing such thing. A basic feature of unit tests is that they have to be predictable, and give the very same results each time they're run. Why? Because you want the code to be totally predictable and the test results completely coherent. Each developer running a test should get the very same result, no matter when, how or in what environment, so they can fix/refactor/develop in a predictable way.

Each test it (or should be) designed to test for **one** particular situation or case. In your case, a hero attacking a monster will produce some certain amount of damage. You're right in that that particular test will cover only one case, and it's correct to do so. It's testing the particular situation that has been designed to do. The benefit of it is that those cases should be representative enough for coverint most situations.

For example, that's a typical test that cover a normal attack situation. A second test will give the hero an attack of 50 and the monster only 30 hitpoints, and will assert that the monster has 0 hitpoints and becomes dead, for example. Yet another may give a shield to the monster, and veryfing that the damage has been reduced. The idea is to create representative cases. An example of a not so useful test would be to add another one with the hero 50 attack and the monster 200 hits, escencially it doesn't do anything conceptually different from your example, and most likely will both pass or both fails.

Edge cases are also useful. What happens if the monster hitpoints and hero's attack are equal? Should it kill or leave almost dead? Another interesting cases can be invalid inputs, that should return errors.

But the general idea is that them being static is a feature for making them reliable and reproducible. One test, one particular thing under test, no more.

Also have a look here: [What are the downsides using random values in Unit Testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441686/what-are-the-downsides-using-random-values-in-unit-testing)

Answer (score 1):

All tests are like that, not only TDD tests. The fundamental problem is that the number of *potential* test inputs is huge. Imagine you had to test a method that took two integers that were 32 bits long and you could write and run 1000 test cases every second. How long would it take you to test *all* the possible inputs? Make a guess, then do the calculation. You might be surprised just how long it would take. Testing is instead selective. We choose a small number of test cases that we hope will do a good enough job of testing, without that testing being perfect.

Part of the skill of testing is knowing how to choose a good set of test cases, which do a good job of testing despite being few in number. It so happens that TDD can do this well because of its insistence on achieving the *green* phase (passing all the tests) by doing the *minimum* that will make the tests pass. Once you have done that, you might well look at your code and see that it is incomplete. That will suggest further test cases, which would be necessary to demonstrate that the code was closer to being complete.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add one or two points to the already excellent answers.

If you had to test this method manually, would you have to go through all values to know that it works? Certainly not. You would test the "normal path", and the edge cases, just like neilh did in his answer. That's what you do when you write automatic unit tests (TDD or not).

Don't think of automatic unit tests as mathematically exhaustive tests. Think of them as a shield that protects you from breaking anything when you refactor your code. Make them cover enough so that they gain your total confidence (that's the really important point), but don't try to cover all of the application's possible states (you can't). You need to **test all possible paths**, which is very different.