# JUnit4 - Test if method does nothing

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4

How can I test if a method does nothing. For example I have a static method that throws an exception if the given string-argument is null or empty (it's meant for argument-validation). Right now my tests look like this:

```
@Test
public void notNullOrEmpty_doesNothingIfValueIsNotNullOrEmpty() {
    Require.notNullOrEmpty(Generate.randomString());
    assertTrue(true); // <- this looks very ugly
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void notNullOrEmpty_throwsExceptionIfValueIsNull() {
    Require.notNullOrEmpty(null);
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void notNullOrEmpty_throwsExceptionIfValueIsEmpty() {
    Require.notNullOrEmpty("");
}
```

How can I make the first test to pass without calling `assertTrue(true)`, there is a `Assert.fail()` is there something like an `Assert.pass()`?

EDIT:
Added missing `(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)` to 3rd test

Comment: In case the Require class does really just check for null or empty consider using the well tested classes from the guava library Preconditions.checkArgument(Strings.isNullOrEmpty("myString"));

Comment: Also keep in mind to carefully use random generated strings as test input. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441686/what-are-the-downsides-using-random-values-in-unit-testing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have just to remove the assert in the first method.

```
@Test
public void notNullOrEmpty_doesNothingIfValueIsNotNullOrEmpty() {
    Require.notNullOrEmpty(Generate.randomString());
    // Test has passed
}
```

If the test method runs completely then it means it pass with success. Look at Eclipse junit output:

[image]

Update: as an additional comment, if you use Mockito framework  you can leverage `verify` method to verify that a method was called X times. For instance, I used something like this:

```
verify(cmAlertDao, times(5)).save(any(CMAlert.class));
```

In your case, since you are testing static methods, then you might find useful using PowerMock which allows you to verify static methods (since Mockito doesn't). And you can use `verifyStatic(...)`.

Comment: so, just not asserting anything will make the test pass?

Comment: @Exhauzt yes, correct. I have added an update to the answer. However,  you could use Mockito framework with `verify` that a method is called X amount. And also you can use PowerMock to verify static methods being called.

Comment: @Exhauzt, just to be clear, if you are using JUnit only, then yes not asserting anything will make the test to pass.

Answer (score 4):

You should add `@Test(expected = YourException.class)` annotation.

Try to add to the first test:

```
@Test
public void notNullOrEmpty_doesNothingIfValueIsNotNullOrEmpty() {
    String str = Generate.randomString();
    Require.notNullOrEmpty(str);
    assertNotNull(str);
}
```

and probably to you have better to rename it to `notNullOrEmpty_doesNothingIfValueIsNotNullOrNotEmpty` because you are testing it for not empty value.

Comment: I have this... for the tests where it should throw an exception. But I want to make the first test clearer

Answer (score 0):

A unit test must assert which is expected in the behavior of the method.
If in your specification, when your call `notNullOrEmpty()`no exception must be thrown when the data is valid and an exception must be thrown when the data is not valid so in your unit test you must do no assertion when the data is valid since if it doesn't success, a exception will be thrown and the test will so be in failure.

```
@Test
public void notNullOrEmpty_doesNothingIfValueIsNotNullOrEmpty() {
    Require.notNullOrEmpty(Generate.randomString());
}
```