# How to press on any available button if there are many same type buttons with Capybara?

Tags: ruby, automation, automated-tests, capybara

I have many buttons, but in my test I don't want to choose/press same button. It will be better test if in random will choose/press any available button.

Code sample with buttons and [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvVjK.png) how it looks in real life

```
<a onclick="ShowDayPopup('clientCode', 'clientObject', '16', '2018.03', '144', 'atk'); return false;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnInsert_1591580_16" class="cool-button blue width73" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnInsert_1591580_16", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Button</a>

<a onclick="ShowDayPopup('clientCode', 'clientObject', '17', '2018.03', '144', 'atk'); return false;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnInsert_1591580_17" class="cool-button blue width73" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnInsert_1591580_17", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Button</a>
```

Comment: *"It will be **better** test if in **random** will choose/press any available button."* (sic) plenty of folks will disagree.

Comment: And the reason of disagree?

Comment: [Some good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441686/what-are-the-downsides-using-random-values-in-unit-testing) for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is generally a bad idea to have random behavior in tests, however to do what you asked in the question you can use `all` to get all matching buttons and then use `sample` to choose a random member. First thing needed would be a selector that chooses all the potential buttons.  Given the HTML you provided you could do that with a CSS selector or use a :link selector and specify the class(es) separately

```
all('a.cool-button', minimum: 1).sample.click
```

or

```
all(:link, class: 'cool-button', minimum: 1).sample.click
```

`minimum: 1` is specified to trigger waiting/retrying behavior in case the buttons are being dynamically loaded on the page (won't be required in Capybara 3.0)

Comment: Thanks, both worked for me.
Will keep in mind about *Some good reasons* why not to use this random